# Redirect the returning site visitor to another URL

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies

The Logic: Someone open my LP (landing page) first time > he closes my LP and go away > he open my LP second time.

So, how can i redirect him to another URL when he opens my Landing page second time?

P.S. I'm a newbie, so better for me is using cookies.

I have been searching stackoverflow and did not find an answer for exactly my question

Comment: on the page check for a localstorage item. If it exists then direct to the other page. If it doesnt exist then create it

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(cookie_name, value, days) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + days);
    var cookie_value = escape(value) + ((days == null) ? '' : ';
    expires=' + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = cookie_name + '=' + cookie_value;
}


function getCookie(cookie_name) {
    var x, y;
    var val = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        x = val[i].substr(0, val[i].indexOf('='));
        y = val[i].substr(val[i].indexOf('=') + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');

        if (x == cookie_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}

if (getCookie("isVisited") === "true") {
  window.location.href = "https://redirect-url";
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).